# Validação de senha salva no SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, validação

Olá eu estou fazendo um projeto pra faculdade e eu sou novo no Android,estou fazendo um aplicativo que o intuito dele é Verificar se a senha está correta pra poder finalizar o aplicativo, porém não estou conseguindo validar a senha, eu não preciso validar outra coisa, apenas a senha.

Eu criei 3 telas uma para cadastro do usuário, onde é cadastrado o e-mail e a senha dele, quando ele cadastra ele vai para outra tela.

A segunda tela onde é pedido a senha para finalizar o app, e é nessa tela que eu preciso que a senha seja validada, para que a senha que ele cadastrou seja a unica que possa finalizar o app.

E a ultima tela é uma para recuperação da senha através do e-mail.

Eu estou usando esse código para o cadastro na primeira tela:

```
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail); //Determinando o ID das coisas
    editSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSenha);

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("CadastroDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cadastro (Email VARCHAR, Senha VARCHAR);");
}

//Botão Cadastrar

public void btnCadastro (View view) {

    if(editEmail.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || editSenha.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
    {
        showMessage("Erro", "Preencha os Campos");
    }

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES('"+editEmail.getText()+"','"+editSenha.getText()+"');");
    showMessage("Ok", "Dados Gravados");
    clearText();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecionando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Agora eu só preciso validar na tela 2 essa senha pra o projeto acabar... Se alguem puder ajudar agradeceria.

Comment: Mostre o que você tem na segunda tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom se você tem que realizar a validação da senha com o email do usuário você pode usar um método que retorna se a senha e o usuário existem no banco de dados, por exemplo:

```
private boolean validaSenha(String senha, String email) {

    // O Cursor recebe o resultado do select
    Cursor cursor = db.execSql("SELECT senha, email FROM cadastro WHERE senha = " + senha + " and email = " + email);

    // Retorna se o cursor tem 1 resultado com o email e senha informados
    return cursor != null && cursor.getCount() == 1;

}
```

Assim você pode fazer a verificação da seguinte forma:

```
if (validaSenha(senha, email)){

    //Código para fechar o aplicativo

}
```

Agora se você quiser realizar a validação somente pela senha, basta remover o parâmetro `email` da função e do select.